# Root system for Lie algebras: If $\alpha, \beta, \alpha - \beta \in \Phi$ are all roots, is $(\alpha, \beta) > 0$?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

Exercise 8.11 of Humphreys' Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory asks to prove that if $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$ and $(\alpha,\beta) > 0$, then $\alpha - \beta \in \Phi$ (presumably it's implicitly assumed that $\beta \neq \alpha$). Is the converse true? It's conceivable that we could have a string $\alpha - \beta, \alpha, \alpha + \beta, \alpha + 2\beta \in \Phi$, so then $\alpha(h_\beta) = 1 - 2 = -1 < 0$, but I don't have a concrete example of this.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is not necessarily true. You'll find an example of your "conceivable" string in [the root system of type $G_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_G2.svg). (Not with the ones that are called $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in this image; rather, to use your terminology, use as $\alpha$ e.g. the upper left short root and as $\beta$ the one that is called $\alpha$ in this image).

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Comment: *Two* downvoters, please explain? In a first version this answer might have been confusing because the image does not use the notation of the question, but now ... what do you think is bad or wrong in this answer?

Comment: @TorstenSchoemeberg$:$ If $\alpha, \beta, \alpha - \beta \in \Phi$ then it implies that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not proportional and $\alpha + \beta \notin \Phi$ (Why?). Hence $(\alpha, \beta) \geq 0$ according to the lemma in section $9.4$ of Humphreys. Am I right?

Comment: See that the given condition implies that one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a positive root and the other one is a negative root. So this forces that $\alpha + \beta \notin \Phi$ since if we fix a basis all the roots can either be uniquely expressed as non-negative integer linear combinations of fundamental roots or as non-positive integer linear combinations of fundamental roots. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In your linked picture if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the one's you mentioned in your answer then $\alpha - \beta$ is the upper left long root. But the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $\frac {5 \pi} {6}.$ So indeed in this case $(\alpha, \beta) \lt 0.$ Don't understand what went wrong in my assertion.

Comment: @AnilBagchi. Not sure if I understand your question, but the example in $G_2$ contains$\alpha, \beta$ such that both $\alpha \pm \beta \in \Phi$. So where you ask "Why" this is actually not true. Also in that example, one can choose $\alpha-\beta, \alpha, \alpha+\beta$ and $\beta$ all as positive roots. A basis would consist of $\alpha-\beta$ and $\beta$. So your statement that "the given condition implies that one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a positive root and the other one is a negative root" is wrong. By the way, no root is positive or negative in itself, that depends on choices.

Comment: No I mean that if you fix a basis then positivity (and hence negativity) of the roots relative to that basis is completely determined. So if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive roots what does that imply? If the basis is given by $\{\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_l \}$ then positivity of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would then imply there exists unique non-negative integers $m_1, \cdots, m_l$ (not all zero) and $n_1, \cdots, n_l$ (not all zero) such that $\alpha = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} m_i \alpha_i$ and $\beta = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} n_i \alpha_i.$ What does it tell us about $\alpha - \beta\ $?

Comment: Oh! My bad. This can only tell that either all $m_i \geq n_i$ or all $m_i \leq n_i.$ So no confusion. Extremely sorry for that.